# Add property to object array created with Array.map

Tags: angular

Using Angular, I have created a table whose content's are generated by two web requests. The first gives the table all of its contents for types of documents and its associated system. The second request is fired by looping through each document type and getting the URL for the document type's system.

I have modified the structure of the array with `Array.map()` and want to add the URL as a property to the object being iterated over:

```
[{
  System: "FIS NetImage",
  Title: "Notices"
}, {
  System: "Nautilus",
  Title: "Reports"
}, {
  System: "FIS NetImage",
  Title: "Statements",
}]
```

I have an `if` statement to add the URL if the iterated item's System matches the URL's system. However, I can't get this to work as I'm getting the following error:

> Error: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'modDocTypes[i_1].SystemLocation = system')

Also, I have realized that this method is not very efficient and will only get worse with having more items in the first array.

How can I add the System's URL from another web request in an efficient way?

[I have created a StackBlitz with the web requests' data output.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cbdad6)

**Edit:** I have corrected the issue of adding the property to the array created with `.map()`. However, this is still a somewhat inefficient method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason here is you are looping through two arrays but they share the same index **i**. So `modDocTypes[i]` may not exist if length of systems is bigger than `modDocTypes`.

you can use `Array.find` to search for a specific item in array.

```
const system = this.systems.find(item => item.Title === modDocType.System);
```

Assume you want to set `Location` of `systems` array to `modDocTypes` array when they keep same `Title` value.

```
modDocTypes.map(modDocType => {
  const system = this.systems.find(item => item.Title === modDocType.System);
  if (system) {
    modDocType['SystemLocation'] =  system.Location;
  }
});
```

See fixed **[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lsgwds?file=src/app/app.component.ts)**.

Comment: Thanks! This works! Is it more efficient than iterating over each item in the array and matching?

Comment: @cfoster5 There is not much performance difference between them. But Array's build-in functions are much more easy to read.